# PrimeFaces Chips addItem(value) to the component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a chips component and I want to add a button beside it and use this button to add values to this component.

My draft code is:

```html
<p:outputPanel>
    <p:chips id="TextToChips" value="#{myBean.myList}" unique="true" />
    <p:button id="addButton">
        <p:ajax event="click" process="TextToChips" update="chips" delay="300" listener="#{myBean.method}" />
    </p:button>
</p:outputPanel>
```

I want to use the method `addItem(value)`, which is listed in the documentation. So how can I use that if my principle is possible?

Comment: Try to use p:commandButton without p:ajax.
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml?jfwid=dfd37

Comment: yep use just `onClick` method of the button to call `PF('yourChips').addItem(yourValue);` Javascript.